# How do I get to the MVVM Light sample application?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm reading through Laurent Bugnion article on MSDN magazine's website [MVVM - IOC Containers and MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991965.aspx). In the article Laurent mentions a sample application that accompanies the article. I can't find a link to that sample app anywhere on the page. I realize it's been a couple of years since the article appeared, but I would think there'd still be a link to the sample app's source code. Where can I find his sample app's source code?

Comment: This it? https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Reversi-XAMLC-sample-board-816140fa

Comment: It could be, I'm not sure. The article didn't say what the associated app was or did. OK, I'll take a look at it, thank you.

Comment: I suspect that the Reversi application isn't an example of an app written using MVVM Light. In looking at some of the view models I see they used DelegateCommand instead of RelayCommand, that MVVM Light uses.

Comment: Go to https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest and inside the folder Samples there is a Flowers folder. This contains a cross platform example of how to use MVVM-Light. Laurent uses that one often in demo's. It has most of the common items used of MVVM-Light